# t-test loop returns 'object not found' error

Tags: r, for-loop

In R, assume there is a data frame "mydata" comprising the independent variable "group" (two groups) and n dependent variables. I want to run n t-tests (one for each dependent variable), print and save the results in a file by doing the following:

```
variables<-names(mydata)
variables<-variables[-1] #to remove the group variable
capture.output(for(i in variables){print(t.test(get(paste("mydata$", i, sep=""))~mydata$group))},file="outputfile.txt")
```

This command returns the following error message:

```
Error in get(paste("mydata$", i, sep = "")) : object 'mydata$variable1' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you used indexing you won't have this problem.

Comment: @TylerRinker i use indexing regularly; but being shitty programmer, i didn't actually know it was called indexing -- so for others who might not know, see this quick reference: http://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/vectorindexing.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For others, some sample data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(group=sample(1:2, 100, replace=T), variable1=rnorm(100), variable2=rnorm(100), variable3=rnorm(100))
```

I'd use the much more straight forward:

```
for(i in variables) {
   t.test(mydata[i], mydata$group)
}
```

if I were using a for loop.  However, you could do this using a more R-like style:

```
lapply(variables, function(v, df=mydata) t.test(df[v], df$group))
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: `get` doesn't work on `$` elements of data frames.

Better answer: Build the entire formula using `paste` and send it to `t.test` as one element.  Also, use `lapply`.

```
set.seed(5)
x <- matrix(round(runif(100,0,10),1), ncol=10)
colnames(x) <- paste("var", 1:ncol(x), sep="")
mydata <- data.frame(group=gl(2,10), x)

variables <- names(mydata)[-1]
names(variables) <- variables

out <- lapply(variables, function(v) {
  t.test(as.formula(paste(v, "~ group")), data=d)
})

out
```